# Максимизировать распределяемую премию

Tags: java, алгоритм, олимпиада

Петр Васильевич, директор ОАО "Рога и рога", собирается раздать премию всем менеджерам компании, он добрый и честный человек, поэтому хочет соблюсти следующие условия:

премия должна быть равной для всех менеджеров
должна быть максимально возможной и целой
должна быть выдана одной транзакцией с одного счета для каждого менеджера, без использования нескольких счетов для отправки одной премии

У Петра Васильевича открыто N корпоративных счетов, на которых лежат разные суммы денег Cn, а в компании работает M менеджеров.
Необходимо выяснить максимальный размер премии, которую можно отправить с учетом условий. Если денег на счетах компании не
хватит на то, чтобы выдать премию хотя бы по 1 у.е. - значит премии не будет, и нужно вывести 0.

Входные данные (поступают в стандартный поток ввода)
Первая строка - целые числа N и M через пробел (1≤N≤100 000, 1≤M≤100 000)

Далее N строк, на каждой из которых одно целое число Cn (0≤Cn≤100 000 000)

Проверка входных данных и обработка неправильных данных на входе не нужна, тестовые данные для проверки гарантированно подходят под описание выше

Выходные данные (ожидаются в стандартном потоке вывода)
Одно целое число, максимально возможная премия

Пример 1
Ввод:

```
3 6
453
220
601
```

Вывод:

```
200
```

Пример 2
Ввод:

```
2 100
99
1
```

Вывод:

```
1
```

Пример 3
Ввод:

```
2 100
98
1
```

Вывод:

```
0
```

Мой алгоритм сортировки

```
Arrays.sort(cn);
int left = cn[0];
int right = cn[cn.length - 1];
int mid = 0;
while (right - left > 1) {
    sum = 0L;
    mid = (right + left) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += cn[i] / mid;
    }
if (sum < m) {
    right = mid;
} else {
    left = mid;    
}
        System.out.println(left);
```

Comment: Вот я смотрю на задачу, и мне кажется, что её надо решать динамическим программированием. Но - надо работать! Но спасибо за задачу!

Comment: Вот не понимаю проблемы. Всего-то и делов что найти максимальное X (сумма премии) такое, что `SUM(INT(Cn/X)) >= M`. Начальное приближение = `INT(SUM(Cn)/M)`, поиск в диапазоне от него до нуля, скажем, половинным делением (что приятно - функция монотонная). При макс. 100кк на счёте - это не более 27 итераций.

Comment: Ну задачи - они специально так написаны, что читаешь - и будто вату в голову засовываешь. Мне приходится чтобы понять, о чем речь - выкинуть весть это бред и НА БУМАГЕ переписать формулировку без всяких Рогов и Копыт.

Comment: никакая это не олимпиада, это задачи отборочного тура для поступления в школу hh

Comment: @tym32167 - ну вот, мы дожили до того, что hh открыл свою школу... Интнрсно, путаться в формулировках условий задач - это традиция, пришедшая из их вакансий?

Comment: @S.H. Не знаю про их традиции, мне было интересно порешать их задачки. Эта задачка простая, вторая посложнее немного, у меня на обе ушёл вечер примерно.

Comment: @S.H. hh открыл школу программистов впервые 12 лет назад и уже 11 лет ее проводит ежегодно, так что мы уже давно дожили.

Касательно формулировок – все задачи составлены таким образом, чтобы во-первых не вызывать разных интерпретаций при внимательном прочтении (что вызывает громоздкость), а во-вторых, чтобы когда кто-то пойдет постить их на всякие сайты в поисках решений - мы легко могли это увидеть (что вызывает уникальность формулировок, имён и названий)

Comment: @Goover - спасибо, я, уже написав комментарий, пошел и почитал про эту школу, и понял свою ошибку. Просто за последний год новые школы программистов появляись довольно часто, а про hh.ru я раньше не знал

Answer (score 1):

Есть очевидное решение с бинпоиском. Перебираем размер премии и проходом по массиву определяем, скольки людям смогли её выдать. Асимптотика O(n*lb(max)).

PS: Думаю, что существует линейное решение, но я его не придумал, а это почти наверняка достаточно хорошее.

Comment: Не очень понятно, у меня в коде так и должно работать, но работает не для всего

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин, во-первых, бинпоиска у тебя в коде нет. Во-вторых, проверка должна быть на `>=`, а не на `==` - подставь 1 работника и несколько счетов и у тебя будет что-то не то. В-третьих, подозреваю, что ты переполнение прозевал в переменной count, но это не точно.

Comment: *Думаю, что существует линейное решение* Функция монотонная и имеет достаточно специфический вид  - лестница. Что позволяет вместо половинного деления на основании двух точек считать следующее приближение. Думаю, что это в среднем уменьшит количество считаемых вариантов приблизительно чуть меньше чем втрое. Это с одной стороны. А с другой - имеется целый диапазон значений аргумента, дающих одно и то же значение функции, и надо найти максимальное из них, что уже точно будет искаться половинным делением. Чисто по прикидке общее количество поисков сократится где-то в полтора-два раза.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, вы говорите половинное деление, что-то еще. 
в моем коде я нахожу сначала общее среднее.
потом вызываю функцию и иду по счетам, если на каждом счете достаточно, то можно брать это среднее, если нет, то уменьшать это среднее

еще ньюанс такой, если на одном счете 1, а на другом 10 и 2, а сотрудников 6, то тот первый счет можно не брать

Comment: @Akina, у меня ощущение, что если брать m = sqrt(n), то можно заполнить массив так, что все остатки встретятся. Тогда будет O(m\*n) = O(n\*sqrt(n)), что тоже пройдёт под ограничения, но хуже логарифма. Хотя может я ошибаюсь и такой пример составить нельзя. В любом случае, бинпоиск проще в реализации (если не косячить с проверками). Линейное - я скорее какой-нибудь расширенный алгоритм Евклида имел в виду.

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин, [Двоичный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) & [Бинарный поиск по ответу](https://wiki.algocode.ru/index.php?title=%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83)

Comment: @Qwertiy не так задал вопрос. неясность заключается в том, что нам не известно число, которое мы должны найти бинарным или линейным поиском.

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин Вот не понял фразы... вообще-то все поиски именно для того и существуют, чтобы найти это самое неизвестное число...

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин, ты вторую ссылку прочитал?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, прочитал. Я пытался сортировать, но сути в моем решении не менялось. я просто такой тупой -______-

Comment: @Qwertiy
 Есть очевидное решение с бинпоиском. Перебираем размер премии и проходом по массиву определяем, скольки людям смогли её выдать. Асимптотика O(n*lb(max)).
а это у меня и выполняет функция

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин, а второй комментарий ты читал?

Comment: @Qwertiy все, до меня дошло. Здесь нужен бинарный поиск, о чем вы и говорили. Но проблема теперь в другом. Я не понимаю как его написать.

Comment: @Эдвард Колобакин По ссылке же есть пример бинарного поиска, а про проверку (аналог check) Akina в комментарии рассказал

Comment: Проверки на одинаковую сумму на счетах и на одного сотрудника не нужны.

Comment: @Qwertiy я обновил свой код и записал только алгоритм сортировки, какой у меня. Подскажите, что здесь не так

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин, во-первых, зачем там вообще сортировка? Во-вторых, при таком условии выхода из цикла у тебя получается 2 значения, отличающихся на 1. Почему ты решил, что ответом является left?

Comment: @Qwertiy для данного поиска сортировка разве не нужна ? потому что оно подходит под условие >= сотрудникам

Comment: @ЭдвардКолобакин, не нужна. Поиск же не по массиву.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант с последовательным перебором от среднего арифметического (максимально возможного) по нисходящей до первого допустимого:**

```js
function largestBonus(N,M,...Cn){
    const accounts = [...Cn];
    const max = Math.floor(accounts.reduce((sum,item) => sum + item, 0)/M);
    for(let b = max; b > 0; b--){
        if(accounts.reduce((sum,item) => sum + Math.floor(item/b), 0) >= M){
            return b;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

console.log(largestBonus(4,6,199,453,220,601));
console.log(largestBonus(2,100,99,1));
console.log(largestBonus(2,100,98,1));
```

**Вариант с двоичным поиском наибольшего из диапазона от 0 до среднего арифметического**:

```js
function largestBonus(N,M,...Cn){
    const accounts = [...Cn];
    let max = Math.floor(accounts.reduce((sum,item) => sum + item,0)/M);
    let min = 0;
    let cur = 0;
    while(max != min){
        cur = Math.ceil((max + min)/2);
        if(accounts.reduce((all,account) => all + Math.floor(account/cur),0) >= M){
            min = cur;
        } else {
            max = cur - 1;
        }
    }
    return cur;
}

console.log(largestBonus(4,6,199,453,220,601));
console.log(largestBonus(2,100,99,1));
console.log(largestBonus(2,100,98,1));
```

Comment: Решение сработает, это плюс. Но оно не оптимальное по скорости.

Comment: вопрос по JavaScript не просто закрыли, автор его удалил. Видимо, чтобы не палиться, ведь это отборочный вопрос в школу hh

Comment: По идее мне проверку в цикле надо сделать, если b < bonus то закончить цикл, это будет оптимальней? Или не решает вопрос? Добавил.

Comment: по идее вместо `for(let b = max; b > 0; b--){` надо пользоваться двоичным поиском.

Comment: Двоичный поиск же для отсортированных данных, а как его здесь применить, для чего собственно? Массив из чего, в котором поиск проходит? Блин, дошло...

Comment: 1) для двоичного поиска массив не обязателен 2) вы и так в этом цикле идете в строгом порядке по убыванию `for(let b = max; b > 0; b--)`

Comment: Да, да, я понял, как раз взять за максимум max за минимум 0 и идти, проверяя возможный бонус. Логично, я даже не углядел линейную зависимость сразу. Сейчас потыркаюсь))

Comment: Если принимать массивы такого размера как в условии, через rest, будет переполнение стека. Но вообще выглядит верно.

Comment: В условии же просто последовательный набор чисел, как мне еще принять можно? Брать как поток и записывать в массив? Я просто логику самого поиска хотел расписать через цикл. Можно и интерфейс забивания данных, конечно, расписать. Или речь о .reduce() всего массива разом?

Answer (score -1):

Решил вот так, но почему то проверку не проходит по второму тесту. Хотя в IDE все окей. Подскажите, если кто что заметит.

```
    function amountOfReward(n, m, accounts) {

    let topLimit = Math.floor(accounts.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0)/m);

    if (topLimit < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (topLimit === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        let bottomLimit = 1;
        let counter = 0;
        let swap = 0;

        while (true) {

            for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                if (accounts[i] / topLimit >= 1) {
                    counter += Math.floor((accounts[i] / topLimit));
                }
            }

            if (counter < m) {
                topLimit = Math.floor(topLimit - (topLimit - bottomLimit) / 2);
                swap = topLimit;
                counter = 0;
            } else if (counter > m) {
                bottomLimit = swap;
                topLimit = Math.floor(topLimit + topLimit / 2);
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                return topLimit;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(amountOfReward(4, 6, [199, 453, 220, 601]));
console.log(amountOfReward(2, 100, [99, 1]));
console.log(amountOfReward(5, 6, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(amountOfReward(3, 5, [25, 37, 3]));
console.log(amountOfReward(4, 27, [199, 453, 220, 601]));
console.log(amountOfReward(1, 2, [1]));
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, вы дали ответ. На ответ вам никто не ответит. [Задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и сошлитесь на текуший, если есть взаимосвязь. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, удалите.